# WPF Tabcontrol TabItem display issue on Windows Classic theme

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have come across an annoying issue in a WPF development (.net 3.5 sp1) I have been undertaking which involves showing some Tabs down the side (and rotated) on my interface.

I have been developing on a Windows 7 machine with the normal Aero theme and the tabs look fine

[image]

When we deployed to the customer, their machines are set on "Windows Classic" theme and the tabs show as

[image]

So they are all 'squashed' and don't display the text. If I switch my machine to Windows Classic then I am able to reproduce.  I looked at the interface with WPF Inspector and could see some padding values that shouldn't be there

[image]

If I change the padding values to 0 using WPF Inspector, then the tabs start showing correctly again !!  I have set the padding to be 0 on the template I have for this, but it doesn't seem to be having any affect

```
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentTabIndex}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPassengers}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="26.5" />
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding NameInGDSFormat}">
                            <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                            </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Lots of stuff in here for the Content Template -->
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I have tried setting various templates, padding on various elements but nothing seems to change - so does anyone know how I can fix this ?

EDIT:  If I remove the 'width' that is set, then it does actually show in Windows Classic - but the tab is very WIDE.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - so in the end I had to create a whole new ControlTemplate to fix the issue :)

Basically I found the following within the original Classic ControlTemplate

```
<ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"
     Content="{TemplateBindingReaderedContentControl.Header}"
     ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
     ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
     ContentSource="Header"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
     Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
     SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
```

So someone thought it a good idea to bind the Margin to the Padding and then when you place the Tabs on the left (or right) the template further added

```
<MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected">
                <Condition.Value>
                    <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                </Condition.Value>
            </Condition>
            <Condition Property="TabItem.TabStripPlacement" Value="{x:Static Dock.Left}"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Control.Padding">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Thickness>11,2,14,2</Thickness>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Thickness>-2,-2,-2,-2</Thickness>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </MultiTrigger>
```

So they set the Padding to 11,2,14,2 (the values I was seeing in WPF Inspector).

So I had to override the Template, set the Margin to something sensible and then set the padding to more realistic values that could handle the content presenter being rotated 270 degrees :)

Hope this helps someone else who comes across this !!